# HTTP_REFERER not in request.META, how to set it?

Tags: django, csrf

I am trying to fix csrf protection for my Django views. The `CsrfViewMiddleware` checks if there is the referer as follows:

```
referer = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')
if referer is None:
    return self._reject(request, REASON_NO_REFERER)
```

I am trying to set the 'HTTP_REFERER' in the headers as such:

```
const config = {
  headers : {
    "Referer": "https://example.com/",
    "HTTP_REFERER": "https://example.com/",
    "Referrer-Policy": "strict-origin-when-cross-origin"
  }
}

const fetcherGraphql = (query) => request(serverURl + "/graphql", query, config);
```

Django fails with `REASON_NO_REFERER` because there is no `HTTP_REFERER`  in the `request.META`

How do I get it in there? Or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know if it worked.

```
delete window.document.referrer;
window.document.__defineGetter__('referrer', function () {
    return "yoururl.com";
});
```

Comment: What is window.document here? I cannot find these. I am using `graphql-request` to do the call

Comment: It's a javascript property. Just add it in your js file before sending the request and let me know if it worked.